# Animation not showing correctly in final render

Tags: animation, particles

I've been doing some animation tests to improve my blender skills, and so I designed a looping abstract design. I have a set of four particle systems running, two to simulate each looping effect. (Have one start at -n/2 frames and end at n/2, other starts at n/2 and ends at 3n/2) When I look at the animation through the view port, it is a perfect loop, but when I render it, the animation doesn't start at the -n/2, and the particles randomly spawn at the center of the screen even though I baked the particle system.

This is what the first frame looks like rendered.

[image]

This is what it should look like. (screen shot, so it wasn't composited etc.)

[image]

As you can see, the particles form a blob in the middle for the first frame of the animation. I wanted to figure out a way to get around it. I'm sure it's something simple, I just can't find what it is. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you baked the particle systems before rendering the animation? If not, do it.

Comment: I already baked the particle system with "Bake all Dynamics." (I did mention that I baked it in the question btw.)

Comment: I don't know it seems you have done everything right, maybe there is a bug with negative frames, try to shift everything by n/2 to start on frame 0 or 1

Comment: I think the problem is from some time-remapping I did. It seems to interfere with the particle system spawn, but only in the final render. Know any way around this?